# FTP, Checkout repository using Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ftp, vcs-checkout

I'm a newbie with this, am wondering in some cases because when I'm trying to FTP the server the file I'm looking for has shown-up but when I'm checking-out using NetBeans for that certain file no data has being retrieved. How come? I'm using windows7